# How to get current path in win98 batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

Please, don't ask me "Why Win98?".

I'm writing batch file for Win98.
I should get in some variable the current directory path. Following examples doesn't work:
`curdir=cd`
`curdir=%cd%`
`curdir="%cd%"` (this works on WinXP and Win7)
Command `cd` hasn't return value in Win98, it prints a path in sdtout only.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is another way to get there?

Comment: I take it you used `set` before those commands?

Comment: Maybe, just I don't know the another way. Command `"%cd%"` works without user's `set` invocation. Like a `$SHELL` on Unix systems.

Comment: Have you tried a dot before the %CD%? Like so: `ECHO.%CD%` (note no space between the echo, the dot, and the command). I'm not sure if that will make a difference, but it's what I see on [this helpful page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/shorts.php).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do "dir" returns you something?

Answer (score 1):

This works in real MS-DOS, which is included with Windows 98.  %~dp0 is a function of the NT command processor, and not available in MS-DOS.

```
@echo off

echo exit|%comspec% /k prompt set CurDir=$P$_| FIND " " > %temp%\~SetCD.bat

call %temp%\~SetCD.bat

echo Current Directory  = %CurDir%

@echo on
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "current directory path"...

To echo the path the script was executed in:

```
echo %~dp0
```

example:  executing that in the bat file C:\temp\testing\mybatch.bat would return "C:\temp\testing\"

That doesn't mean that the OS is currently using that path as the system's current directory.